# Independence of Gaussian function and Gradient at each point

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, independence

I am studying Gaussian processes and I found this results, that seems pretty remarkable to me, but yet I can not find anything online about it. I would be very grateful if someone could help me, with a proof or a good reference to read about it.

So if we have $ {f(t), t\in T\subseteq R^2} $, $ C^1 $ centered stationary Gaussian process then why for any fixed t, $ \nabla f(t) $ and $ f(t) $  are **jointly continuous** (apparently we can just assume this?), but **independent**?

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: Do you have a reference for where you got the result? It certainly isn't true for $T \subset \mathbb{R}$ with differentiable covariance functions

Comment: I am sorry, I edited... the process has to be stationary .. there is a more general version in Adler's book..random fields and geometry, but I was hoping to find a more simple way to think about this

Comment: Don't worry I should be able to give you an answer, at least for covariance functions of the form $k(x,y) = k(\| x - y \|)$

Comment: I am of course not saying that the processes themselves are intependent, but the result is for a fixed point...so if the Gaussian process is stationary (which I think is exactly what you said) and we fix a $ t \in \mathbb R $ , then the random variables $ f(t) $ and $ f'(t) $ are independent.

Answer (score 2):

All the relevant details are contained in the one dimensional case, therefore letting $s,t \in \mathbb{R}$ suppose you have
$$
\mbox{cov}(f(s),f(t)) = \omega\left( \frac{|s-t|^2}{2} \right), 
$$
now Gaussian processes are closed under linear transformations, taking the derivative is a linear transformation of your original gaussian processes with new covariance function given by
$$
\begin{align*}
\mbox{cov}\left(\dot{f}(s) , f(t) \right) &= (s-t) \cdot \omega^{\prime}\left( \frac{|s-t|^2}{2}\right), \\
\mbox{cov}\left(f(s), \dot{f}(t) \right) &= (t-s) \cdot \omega^{\prime}\left( \frac{|s-t|^2}{2}\right), \\
\mbox{cov}\left( \dot{f}(s), \dot{f}(t) \right)&= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial s \partial t}\omega\left(\frac{|s-t|^2}{2} \right).
\end{align*}
$$
therefore whenever $s=t$ the covariance between $f(t)$ and $\dot{f}(t)$ vanishes and you get the desired independence. I should stress that we can claim independence because they are jointly Gaussian, infact supposing $f(t)$ is a mean zero Gaussian process with covariance function as above then 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
f(s) \\ f(t) \\ \dot{f}(s) \\ \dot{f}(t)
\end{bmatrix} \sim \mathcal{N}\left( \textbf{0} ,
\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12} \\
\Sigma_{21} & \Sigma_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\right)
$$ 
with
$$
\begin{align}
\Sigma_{11} &= \begin{bmatrix}
\mbox{cov}(f(s),f(s)) & \mbox{cov}(f(s),f(t))\\
\mbox{cov}(f(t),f(s)) & \mbox{cov}(f(t),f(t))
\end{bmatrix}\\
\Sigma_{12} &= \begin{bmatrix}
\mbox{cov}(f(s),\dot{f}(s)) & \mbox{cov}(f(s) ,\dot{f}(t)) \\
\mbox{cov}(f(t),\dot{f}(s)) & \mbox{cov}(f(t) ,\dot{f}(t)) 
\end{bmatrix} \\
\Sigma_{22} &= \begin{bmatrix}
\mbox{cov}(\dot{f}(s),\dot{f}(s)) & \mbox{cov}(\dot{f}(s),\dot{f}(t))\\
\mbox{cov}(\dot{f}(t),\dot{f}(s)) & \mbox{cov}(\dot{f}(t),\dot{f}(t))
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
The same argument will go through in exactly the same way for higher dimensions just by redefining the covariance function as $\omega(\frac{1}{2}\| \textbf{s} - \textbf{t} \|^2)$.

Here is a reference that contains the necessary details for infinitely differentiable squared exponential kernel [Derivative observations in Gaussian Process Models of Dynamic Systems](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/pub/pdf/SolMurLeietal03.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much ! Could  you explain to me the  first line though? I get that we have the covariance only depending on $ |s-t| $, as our process is stationary..but how do you have a function of $ |s-t|^2 $ please?

Comment: I'm taking the covariance to be stationary in the sense that it is dependent on the distance $|s - t| $ between points, and to make sure it is differentiable at the point $s=t$ I squared it - we need the covariance function to be at least twice differentiable I think to talk about the gradient field existing